# How to config Mac OS X firewall to let http (80) request in?

Tags: macos, firewall

I hava installed xampp in my Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan). It works fine when I type `http://192.168.0.63` (my IP address) into my browser, but others in the same network can't access through `http://192.168.0.63` unless I close my firewall.

Any suggestions to help configure the firewall to allow incoming connections through port 80?